# How verify account's password

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am asking account's password(password for login in mac) in my application. How can I verify password which is entered user?

I think something like it, but it doesn't work:

```
-(BOOL)authenticatePassword:(char *)password adminName:(char *)userName
{

    BOOL retValue = NO;

    OSStatus status,status1;
    AuthorizationFlags flag;
    AuthorizationItem items[2];
    items[0].name = kAuthorizationEnvironmentPassword;
    items[0].value = password;
    items[0].valueLength = strlen(password);
    items[0].flags = 0;

    items[1].name = kAuthorizationEnvironmentUsername;
    items[1].value = userName;
    items[1].valueLength = strlen(userName);
    items[1].flags = 0;

    AuthorizationItemSet itemSet = {2,items};
    status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, &itemSet, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorization_);
    if(status == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
        AuthorizationRights rights = {2,&items};
        //AuthorizationEnvironment kEnviroment = {2, items};
        AuthorizationFlags flag1 = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults;
        status1 = AuthorizationCopyRights(authorization_, &rights,NULL, flag1, NULL);

        if(status1 == errAuthorizationSuccess) {
            retValue = YES;
        }
    }

    return retValue;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `AuthorizationCopyRights`call the user credentials for the validation should be in the environment parameter (your commented out line) and the rights parameter really should contain the rights you would like to gain using this user credentials.

The rights can contain built in rights or user created rights, it's simpler to use a built in one because creating a user defined right requires admin privilege.

This code bellow will do the trick for you, just call `AuthenticateForRight` with the username/password parameter and it will try to gain the **allow** right that is a built in one in the authorizationDB and requires a valid user credential.

To use with a custom right you should once call `SetupAuthorizationForRight` with admin rights for the right be created in the authenticationDB, after that you can check the user credentials anytime via `AuthenticateForRight` as a normal user just pass the rightName param also you passed for `SetupAuthorizationForRight` first time.

```
// original code: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2095/_index.html
//                https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-BCIGEHDI


bool SetupAuthorizationForRight(const char* rightName)
// Called as the application starts up. Creates a connection
// to Authorization Services and then makes sure that our
// right is defined.
{
    OSStatus err;

    // Connect to Authorization Services.

    AuthorizationRef authorization = NULL;
    err = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, NULL, 0, &authorization);

    // Set up our rights.

    if (err == noErr) {
        // Check whether our right is already defined.
        err = AuthorizationRightGet(rightName, NULL);
        if (err == noErr) {

            // A right already exists, either set up in advance by
            // the system administrator or because this is the second
            // time we've run. Either way, there's nothing more for
            // us to do.

        } else if (err == errAuthorizationDenied) {

            // The right is not already defined. Let's create a
            // right definition based on the custom (not canned) rule defined
            // in the dictionary below.
            // The system administrator can modify this right as they
            // see fit.
            CFStringRef keys[2] = {CFSTR("class"), CFSTR("group")};
            CFStringRef values[2] = {CFSTR("user"), CFSTR("everyone")};
            // Allow access for every user - all of local and remote users are in the
            // 'everyone' group, so this is a safe rule
            CFDictionaryRef aDict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)keys, (const void **)values, 2,
                                                       &kCFCopyStringDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
                                                       &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

            err = AuthorizationRightSet(
                                        authorization,          // authRef
                                        rightName,              // rightName
                                        aDict,                  // rightDefinition
                                        CFSTR("Authenticate to log in via YourAppName."),          // descriptionKey
                                        NULL,                   // bundle, NULL indicates main
                                        NULL                    // localeTableName,
                                        ); // NULL indicates "Localizable.strings"

            if (aDict) {
                CFRelease(aDict);
            }

            if (err != noErr) {
                NSLog(@"Cannot set up authorization entry. Error: %d", err);
            }
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cannot open authorization database. Error: %d", err);
    }

    return (err == noErr);
}

bool AuthenticateForRight(const char* username, const char* password, const char* rightName)
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;

    if (rightName) {
        if ((status = SetupAuthorizationForRight(rightName)) != noErr)
            return false;
    }
    else
        rightName = "allow"; // Allow right rule always defined by default and only authenticated users has this right

    AuthorizationRef authRef = 0;

    AuthorizationItem   environment[2] = {{NULL, 0, NULL, 0}, {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}};
    int numItems = 0;
    if (username) {
        AuthorizationItem item = { kAuthorizationEnvironmentUsername, strlen(username), (char*)username, 0 };
        environment[numItems++] = item;
        if (password) {
            AuthorizationItem passItem = { kAuthorizationEnvironmentPassword, strlen(password), (char*)password, 0 };
            environment[numItems++] = passItem;
        }
    }

    AuthorizationItem right = {NULL, 0, NULL, 0};
    right.name = rightName;
    right.valueLength = 0;
    right.value = 0;
    AuthorizationRights rightSet = { 1, &right };
    AuthorizationRights environmentSet = { static_cast<unsigned int>(numItems), environment };

    status = AuthorizationCreate(NULL, &environmentSet, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authRef);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Cannot create authorization reference. Error: %d", status);
        return false;
    }

    AuthorizationFlags flags = kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights | kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize;     // | kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed; <- Just for debugging, will display the OS auth dialog if needed!!! 
    status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authRef, &rightSet, &environmentSet, flags, NULL );
    AuthorizationFree(authRef,kAuthorizationFlagDestroyRights);

    return (status == noErr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`authorization services API` will verify and prompt again if password is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for your reference.

```
char *password = "password";
char *userName = "account";

AuthorizationRef authorization = NULL; 
AuthorizationItem items[2];
items[0].name = kAuthorizationEnvironmentPassword;
items[0].value = password;
items[0].valueLength = strlen(password);
items[0].flags = 0;
items[1].name = kAuthorizationEnvironmentUsername;
items[1].value = userName;
items[1].valueLength = strlen(userName);
items[1].flags = 0;

AuthorizationRights rights = {2, items};
AuthorizationEnvironment enviroment = {2, items};
// Creates a new authorization reference and provides an option to authorize or preauthorize rights.
AuthorizationCreate(NULL, &enviroment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &authorization);
AuthorizationFlags flag = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults| kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

OSStatus status = AuthorizationCopyRights(authorization, &rights, &enviroment, flag, NULL);
if(status == errAuthorizationSuccess)
{
    NSLog(@"Pass");
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Fail");
}
```